# Integration tests in Akka in Scala only pass intermittently

Tags: scala, akka, integration-testing, apache-kafka

I'm trying to write integration tests for Kafka in Scala (and am a bit new to both of these); by integration tests I mean I have a `ClosedShape` `RunnableGraph` in my main code, which I would like to feed data into via a Kafka topic and then examine what comes out via a Kafka topic (as opposed to unit-testing an individual Flow within that `RunnableGraph`).

Here's a simplified example:

```
import akka.NotUsed
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.kafka.{ProducerSettings, ConsumerSettings}
import akka.kafka.scaladsl.{Producer, Consumer}
import akka.kafka.scaladsl.Consumer.Control
import akka.stream.ClosedShape
import akka.stream.scaladsl._
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.{ConsumerRecord, ConsumerConfig}
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.{StringSerializer, StringDeserializer}
import GraphDSL.Implicits._

object SimpleKafkaStream {

  def apply(sourceTopic: String, targetTopic: String, kafkaBootstrapServer: String) (implicit actorSystem: ActorSystem) = {

    RunnableGraph.fromGraph (GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder: GraphDSL.Builder[NotUsed] =>
      source(sourceTopic, kafkaBootstrapServer) ~> transformMessage(targetTopic) ~> target(kafkaBootstrapServer)
      ClosedShape
    })
  }

  private def transformMessage (targetTopic: String) = Flow[ConsumerRecord[String, String]]
    .map (_.value())
    .map ("hello " + _)
    .map (message => { new ProducerRecord[String, String] (targetTopic, message) })

  private def source (topic: String, bootstrapServer: String) (implicit actorSystem: ActorSystem) : Source[ConsumerRecord[String, String], Control] = {
    val consumerSettings = ConsumerSettings(actorSystem, new StringDeserializer, new StringDeserializer, Set(topic))
      .withBootstrapServers(bootstrapServer)
      .withGroupId(s"consumer_1_.$topic")
      .withClientId(s"consumer_1_.$topic")
      .withProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest")
      .withProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "1000")
      .withProperty(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "true")
    Consumer.plainSource(consumerSettings)
  }

  private def target (bootstrapServer: String) (implicit actorSystem: ActorSystem) = {
    Producer.plainSink(ProducerSettings(actorSystem, new StringSerializer, new StringSerializer)
      .withBootstrapServers(bootstrapServer))
  }
}
```

This is then tested with:

```
import java.util.UUID

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.kafka.{ConsumerSettings, ProducerSettings}
import akka.kafka.scaladsl.{Consumer, Producer}
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.testkit.javadsl.TestSink
import akka.stream.testkit.scaladsl.TestSource
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.{StringDeserializer, StringSerializer}
import org.scalatest.{Matchers, WordSpec}

class SimpleKafkaStreamTest extends WordSpec with Matchers {

  "A person should be greeted" in new TestScope {
    startStream()
    send("World")
    requestNext() shouldBe "hello World"
  }

  trait TestScope extends E2EConfiguration with Kafka

  trait E2EConfiguration {
    implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem("e2e-system")
    implicit val actorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()
    val kafkaBootstrapServer = "192.168.99.100:9092"
    val sourceTopic = "person"
    val targetTopic = "greeting"
  }

  trait Kafka {
    this: E2EConfiguration =>

    private val consumerSettings = ConsumerSettings(actorSystem, new StringDeserializer, new StringDeserializer, Set(targetTopic))
      .withBootstrapServers(kafkaBootstrapServer)
      .withGroupId(UUID.randomUUID().toString)
      .withClientId(UUID.randomUUID().toString)
      .withProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest")

    val kafkaInputSource =
      TestSource.probe[String].map( name => {
        new ProducerRecord[String, String] (sourceTopic, name)
    }).to(Producer.plainSink(ProducerSettings(actorSystem, new StringSerializer, new StringSerializer)
      .withBootstrapServers(bootstrapServers = kafkaBootstrapServer))).run()

    val kafkaOutput = Consumer.plainSource(consumerSettings).runWith(TestSink.probe(actorSystem))
    def requestNext() = kafkaOutput.requestNext.value

    def send(name: String) = kafkaInputSource.sendNext(name)

    def startStream() = {
      SimpleKafkaStream(sourceTopic = sourceTopic, targetTopic = targetTopic, kafkaBootstrapServer = kafkaBootstrapServer).run()
    }
  }
}
```

So, this should write "World" to the topic "person", and get back "hello World" in the topic "greeting"... and occasionally this is what happens.  Most of the time, however, I get:

```
Expected OnNext(_), yet no element signaled during 3 seconds
java.lang.AssertionError: Expected OnNext(_), yet no element signaled during 3 seconds
    at akka.stream.testkit.TestSubscriber$ManualProbe.expectNext(StreamTestKit.scala:268)
    at akka.stream.testkit.TestSubscriber$ManualProbe.expectNext(StreamTestKit.scala:259)
    at akka.stream.testkit.TestSubscriber$Probe.requestNext(StreamTestKit.scala:631)
    at kafka.SimpleKafkaStreamTest$Kafka$class.requestNext(SimpleKafkaStreamTest.scala:56)
    at kafka.SimpleKafkaStreamTest$$anonfun$1$$anon$1.requestNext(SimpleKafkaStreamTest.scala:18)
    at kafka.SimpleKafkaStreamTest$$anonfun$1$$anon$1.<init>(SimpleKafkaStreamTest.scala:22)
    at kafka.SimpleKafkaStreamTest$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(SimpleKafkaStreamTest.scala:18)
    at kafka.SimpleKafkaStreamTest$$anonfun$1.apply(SimpleKafkaStreamTest.scala:18)
    at kafka.SimpleKafkaStreamTest$$anonfun$1.apply(SimpleKafkaStreamTest.scala:18)
```

The data hasn't been picked up by Kafka at all.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Right, figured it out myself in the absence of any contribution from the Net of a Million Lies.  For the benefit of anyone else who runs into same issue, here's what needed fixing in the above code:

- `ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG` needs to be `"latest"`, not `"earliest"`, to take the latest entries from the queue.
- Secondly, the above code does not give the ActorSystem a chance to shut down properly and notify Kafka that both consumers (one in the test code, one in the code under test) are now dead.  Without this, the queues will remain locked until the session timeout period (which defaults to 30") elapses, and any subsequent run of the tests will not be able to read the Kafka queues.  Fix by having the test class extend also `BeforeAndAfterAll` and include, in an `afterAll` method, `Await.result (actorSystem.terminate(), 20.seconds)` (10" is not long enough).
- Thirdly, I found offset commits would sometimes repeatedly fail and be immediately rescheduled, and that this could go on for as much as 24" seconds (though I'm sure longer is possible).  This made `kafkaOutput.requestNext()` (`kafkaOutput` is actually a `TestSubscriber.Probe[String]`) unfit for purpose; it was necessary instead to use `kafkaOutput.requestNext(2.seconds)}` (to give the code a chance to do its processing in a `try` block catching `AssertionError`s of the form `"Expected OnNext(_), yet no element signaled`[etc]`"` and retrying up to enough times to be significantly over the 24" period mentioned above.